# get http request params in java appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

I want to make simple web page with google appengine with gwt in eclipse.

All I want is getting params from the URL and printing it in the screen itself

what should I do?

URL looks like  https://myapp.appspot.com/mytest.html?param1=hello&param2=world

and in the web page it would display

param1=hello
param2=world

something like that... 
I don't know how to start...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting parameters in app engine is the same as in any java servlet application: using `request.getParameter("param1")`.

Displaying the value on the page is a different thing. If your view is .jsp, then (with jstl): `${param.param1}`.

Comment: I'm the beginner I don't know how to start really... :-( where can I put those lines? in my java file?

Comment: well, read a tutorial about java servlets. Make a hello world on a local tomcat. Then start using GAE

Comment: Shouldn't that be `${param.param1}`? Or is it different in GAE?

Comment: This answer is for servlets.How can I get the request and headers using App Engine Endpoints ?